# Is it possible to activate a servlets doGet() from an EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, get, ejb

I have a unique scenario where I'm using a servlet to dynamically output  to the browser with calls to a database. The content type is RSS-XML so that it can update an RSS feed xml from the database.  This is working fine. However, I also have a an EJB that is accessable as a webservice @WebService. So that all of it's public methods are accessible via SOAP transactions. I have successfully implemented this as well. So that I am updating the database through Java-WS/SOAP, my problem is that I am not simultaneously updating the doGet() of the servlet which means it's not updating the Servlet call--even though the Database is successfully updated.

How do I force a doGet() call to my servlet from an EJB?  The only way those HTML/XML tags will be updated is if the Servlet is called and therefore the doGet() method.

Thank you.

EDIT for clarity: My Servlet currently is accessed from a jsp page as a URL. It's referenced as a link that people can click on. It updates fine once people click on it but since it is an RSS feed I would also like to be able to call/update the feed when I add data to the database. So far I can add data but the feed is not being updated because I don't know how to call the doGet() in my business logic.

This is what the pertinent part of my servlet looks like:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {

    Statuses = rssbean.arrayUpdates();

    XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
        response.setContentType("application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");


        writer.writeStartDocument();
        writer.writeStartElement("rss");
        writer.writeAttribute("version", "2.0");
        writer.writeStartElement("channel");
for(int i = 0; i < (Statuses.length); i++){
                writer.writeStartElement("item");
                    writer.writeStartElement("title");
                        writer.writeCharacters(Statuses[i]);
                    writer.writeEndElement();
                    writer.writeStartElement("link");
                        writer.writeCharacters("http://www.link.com");
                    writer.writeEndElement();
                    writer.writeStartElement("description");

                    writer.writeEndElement();
                writer.writeEndElement();
```

As you can see I'm creating this .rss file on the fly through doGet(). This works fine when you link to it but I'm not sure how to run these writer calls from my EJB (not the browser).

Comment: Or should I just do some kind of refresh or recalling within the servlet itself so that it's constantly updating. I don't think it is possible to make a call like that to a Servlet from inside your business logic. Servlets are meant for HTTP requests.

Comment: What do you mean with 'updating the doGet()'? Are you caching the data from the database in the web service, as well as in the servlet?

Comment: I don't quite get it--wouldn't the servlet refresh its output from the DB once it's called? If not, set a flag indicating the servlet needs to refresh its cache, however its caching.

Comment: Yes that would probably work refreshing the cache or reloading the page but how do you do that is my question. Can I do it with a call from inside my logic bean?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? In case someone is calling the servlet again, your rssbean would fetch the latest changes at the database, didn't it? So the output would be as you expect. Are you currently running into problems with your approach?

Comment: You're right if some one clicks it does update fine. But since it's an RSS feed and after they click the link it gets added to their feed reader. For example the MOzilla feed reader will take the link once and from there it remembers the reference. There is no link clicking it just waits for updates. I guess I could auto refresh the URL every 2 minutes but I was hoping that i could call the servlet directly after I make the database update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rssBean.arrayUpdates() need to query the database and return the result each time. If it is returning some pre-existing data, then that wont work.

Once you click on a link and access a servlet, the servlet pulls the information from the database and gives the result to the client.

When you update your data through the web service, there is no need to make a call to the servlet to make sure it is updated, as you seem to expect to do.

HTTP is request / response. Once a response has been given to the client, then they would have to refresh the page or click on the link to refresh the content.

see also HTTP headers for cache control http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: the rssBean.arrayUpdates() does query the database. That part is working great. It's the updating of the doGet() that is not being done. Yes if I click the reference from a URL it will update but I can't expect a user to click the URL when I update my database. They have no idea when that is.

Comment: Is the jsp or the web browser caching your result? Did you try a reload on the page?

Comment: Let me explain, you calling doGet is not going to update the client. *Period*. 
When they subscribe to your feed, and go to your feed *link* they will see the latest content.

Comment: That's what I thought too. But at least the feed reader I am using is not triggering the doGet() method it appears to be scanning the cached data and waiting for changes there. I think some ones suggestion that I do an auto refresh or reload might be my only option.

Comment: Debug your servlet, that is, from your feed reader when you recieve a request to that specific servlet/link ... debug and see what is going on. Is that method being called? if so is the data is reloaded? Some problems could be solved by setting some HTTP headers to no-cache.

Comment: @Wintermute I think it is caching my results. The feed does not get updated unless I refresh the URL somehow. I was hoping that I could trigger this refresh from an EJB, however. I'd like to push the updates that way.

Comment: @r0ast3d I will try that. Thanks. I think the problem might be that RSS readers do not call doGet(). If they did it would definetly be udpated. Thanks for your help I think I will do some further research now.